# Mongodb (code=exited, status=14) failed but not any clear errors

Tags: mongodb

I have VPS with `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS` with `Mongodb` and my script was working until 3 days ago fine, but suddenly my hosting server was rebooted (I purchased it from a hosting company) and when my server was boot again, I saw my website was not working and did not connect to database. The result of `systemctl status mongod` is:

```
 mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-10-29 22:47:35 +0330; 17h ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 2800 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=14)
 Main PID: 2800 (code=exited, status=14)

Oct 29 22:47:35 MYHOSTNAME systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Oct 29 22:47:35 MYHOSTNAME systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=14/n/a
Oct 29 22:47:35 MYHOSTNAME systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

When I restart the service, nothing happens. I checked `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` and this is the log:

```
2020-10-30T15:53:39.251+0330 I REPL     [signalProcessingThread] Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown, waitTime: 10000ms
2020-10-30T15:53:39.458+0330 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down the LogicalSessionCache
2020-10-30T15:53:39.460+0330 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2020-10-30T15:53:39.460+0330 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2020-10-30T15:53:39.461+0330 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down the global connection pool
2020-10-30T15:53:39.461+0330 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down the PeriodicThreadToAbortExpiredTransactions
2020-10-30T15:53:39.462+0330 I REPL     [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down the ReplicationCoordinator
2020-10-30T15:53:39.462+0330 I SHARDING [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down the ShardingInitializationMongoD
2020-10-30T15:53:39.463+0330 I COMMAND  [signalProcessingThread] Killing all open transactions
2020-10-30T15:53:39.463+0330 I -        [signalProcessingThread] Killing all operations for shutdown
2020-10-30T15:53:39.463+0330 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor
2020-10-30T15:53:39.463+0330 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down free monitoring
2020-10-30T15:53:39.464+0330 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down free monitoring
2020-10-30T15:53:39.466+0330 I FTDC     [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down full-time data capture
2020-10-30T15:53:39.466+0330 I FTDC     [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down full-time diagnostic data capture
2020-10-30T15:53:39.470+0330 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down the HealthLog
2020-10-30T15:53:39.471+0330 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down the storage engine
2020-10-30T15:53:39.472+0330 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
2020-10-30T15:53:39.472+0330 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down session sweeper thread
2020-10-30T15:53:39.472+0330 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] Finished shutting down session sweeper thread
2020-10-30T15:53:39.648+0330 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2020-10-30T15:53:39.648+0330 I -        [signalProcessingThread] Dropping the scope cache for shutdown
2020-10-30T15:53:39.648+0330 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] now exiting
2020-10-30T15:53:39.648+0330 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] shutting down with code:0
```

I did `telnet localhost 27017` and it works fine and connects (it's closed for remote connections).

I removed `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock` manually, checked ownership of `/var/log/mongodb` and `/var/lib/mongodb` and everything is correct. I also did `chown -R mongodb:mongodb` on both folders to correct them if any incorrect ownership has happened during sudden reboot, but nothing worked.

By the way, when I run `/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf` command, my website runs, I can login to my user account and etc. I am currently doing this in a `screen` to run my website currently, but I do not know how to find the problem and fix it.

Would you help me to check what's wrong with MongoDB and how to fix it? Also like `nginx -t` that tests config file, is there any similar command? I read `man mongod` but found nothing.

**edited to add `/etc/mongodb.conf` contents**:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

security:
  authorization: enabled

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Comment: Can you please provide the conf file

Comment: Sure, it's added to the end of question. I see no changes in the file and `security` block is what my script needs and it's been working fine with this block before. If there's anything wrong with it, I didn't understand. Thanks

Comment: Try to set the [processManagement.pidFilePath](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/index.html#processManagement.pidFilePath) Check the service file `/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` - which user runs the service? `mongod` or `mongodb`?

Comment: `mongodb` is the user I see when I use `vi` for this file, is that what you mean? I checked this link, but I did not find any pid file, neither in `/var/run/mongodb` which is empty, nor `/var/lib/mongodb` which only has a `mongodb.lock` file.

Comment: Could you please run `/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf` with **mongodb** user once and also check **ls -ld /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock**

Comment: @ROHITKHURANA When I run it, it terminates the command and exits after some seconds. `srwx------  1 mongodb nogroup    0 Nov  9 15:36 mongodb-27017.sock=` is the result of `ls -l /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock=`.

Comment: can you also share output of **cat /etc/passwd | grep mongodb** and  **cat /etc/group | grep mongodb**

Comment: @ROHITKHURANA grep result of passwd: `mongodb:x:107:65534::/home/mongodb:/usr/sbin/nologin`. grep result of group file: `mongodb:x:111:mongodb` And the path `/home/` is an empty directory with no directories within.

Comment: As per shared logs.. logs file is **/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock** while on permission output socket is **/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock=**. Have you changed anything between.


2020-10-30T15:53:39.460+0330 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] **removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock**

Comment: No, I have not changed anything. Server was running and up and working, suddenly my hosting provider reboots my server and boom, the result is the current issue I face.

Comment: The log you post does not include the error, are you cutting pieces out? There should be a log with `s:"F"` meaning severity fail.

Comment: @Minsky I did not remove anything in the question. What do you mean by `s:"F"`?

Comment: It means severity fail, and it's the log when the system actually fails starting. Also, I'd look if the mongod.lock file under the `dbpath` is empty, it should be 0B. Another thing to check it the systemd log, there could be relevant data there, from the system itself

Comment: @Minsky I dug into `/var/log/syslog` with thorough investigation and figured out it seems `/var/lib/mongodb/` ownership has issues and some files seemed to have `root:root` ownership, so I `chown`ed all of them to `mongodb:mongodb` and now it's running normally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out the issue by doing a thorough investigation in `/var/log/syslog` with grepping mongo.

I did `chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb/` and terminated my `screen` command, then restarted `mongod` service and then checking `status`, so now the service and my website is running without issue.

**The better version of the solution, run these commands:**

```
chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb/
systemctl restart mongod
```

Answer (score 100):

Try this, it worked for me:

```sh
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock    
sudo service mongod restart
```

Comment: Hi there! This answer worked for me too, for the same issue. However, do you have any idea as to why it worked? How even is the 'mongodb' user generated? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: In my case, only `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock` needed to be updated. The owner/permissions of `/var/lib/mongodb` were already correct.

Comment: Care to add a little information why that happened and why changing permission worked? Thanks

Comment: wow this works for me also, thanks

Comment: Well, I accidentally starting mongod by non-sudo user and got me here. Saved the day by these chown answer.

Comment: to others, in fact, you may have started mongo as non-root. So you got this mistake.You can perform `mongod` to check the output to verify my statement.

Answer (score 15):

In my case the user is mongod and the folder in `/var/lib` folder is `mongo`, so I had to run this command

```
chown -R mongod:mongod /var/lib/mongo/
chown mongod:mongod /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock

systemctl restart mongod
```

Comment: I appreciate you participate and answer. Yes, the user may differ in different distros and settings, and you can figure it out by watching `mongo`'s conf file

Comment: u may find the user name of mongo by:  cat /etc/passwd

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to /tmp and find mongodb sock

   `cd /tmp; ls -l *.sock`
2. Change the owner of that .sock file, it used to named as mongodb-27017.sock, but if you find it in a different name, its ok.

   `chown -R mongod:mongod /var/lib/mongo`

   `chown mongod:mongod mongodb-27017.sock`

if the result come like this chown: invalid user: `mongod:mongod` then it means that the user and group for mongodb was not mongod.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a late answer, but since this issue is a known one in Ubuntu for `mongodb`, I recommend this:

1. Create a file called `/root/mongo.sh` with below contents:

```
chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb/
systemctl restart mongod
```

2. Run `chmod +x /root/mongo.sh` in teminal
3. Add that to crontab via running `crontab -e`:

```
0 2 * * * /root/mongo.sh
```

Now it runs this file each day at 02:00 A.M. and you won't worry.

If you see the issue during the day, only run this:

```
/root/mongo.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I killed all the process already running one by one with the name mongo

```
    root@lancer:/mongodb# ps -ef | grep mongo
root       721 27584  0 Sep27 pts/7    00:00:00 sudo nano mongo.conf
root       722   721  0 Sep27 pts/7    00:00:00 nano mongo.conf
root       736 27584  0 Sep27 pts/7    00:00:00 sudo nano mongo.conf
root       737   736  0 Sep27 pts/7    00:00:00 nano mongo.conf
root       779 27584  0 Sep27 pts/7    00:00:00 sudo nano mongo.conf
root       780   779  0 Sep27 pts/7    00:00:00 nano mongo.conf
root       873 27584  0 Sep27 pts/7    00:00:00 vi mongo.conf
root      1102     1  0 Sep27 ?        00:03:34 mongod --dbpath /mongodb/data --logpath /mongodb/log/mongod.log --fork
root      1150 27584  0 Sep27 pts/7    00:00:02 mongosh
root     10858  5566  0 Sep20 pts/7    00:00:00 sudo systemctl status mongod
root     12386 27584  0 16:27 pts/7    00:00:00 vi mongod.conf
root     13091 27584  0 16:48 pts/7    00:00:00 sudo systemctl status mongod
root     13092 13091  0 16:48 pts/7    00:00:00 systemctl status mongod
root     13258 27584  0 16:52 pts/7    00:00:00 sudo adduser mongod
root     13459 27584  0 16:52 pts/7    00:00:00 sudo adduser mongodb
root     13507 13460  0 16:53 pts/7    00:00:00 /usr/bin/chfn mongodb
root     14091 27584  0 17:37 pts/7    00:00:00 mongo
root     16620 27584  0 20:32 pts/7    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mongo
root     19169 27584  0 11:25 pts/7    00:00:00 vi mongod.service
root     24606 22371  0 Sep27 pts/7    00:00:00 mongo
root     24763 22371  0 Sep27 pts/7    00:00:00 vi mongodb.conf
root     29184 27584  0 Sep27 pts/7    00:00:00 sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service
root     29185 29184  0 Sep27 pts/7    00:00:00 nano /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service 


and then did

root@lancer:/# sudo systemctl start mongod
root@lancer:/# sudo systemctl status mongod

● mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-09-28 20:39:09 IST; 33s ago
 Main PID: 16836 (mongod)
```

Then it starts running successfully.

Comment: You can kill all mongo processes `killall mongo` instead of `kill PID`

Answer (score 0):

Checked **/etc/mongod.conf** - it referenced

```
pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile
```

Checked **/var/run** (there was no mongodb)

```
mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb
chown mongod.mongod /var/run/mongodb
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start mongod
systemctl status mongod
```

This seemed like it worked ... but it didn't

Credit to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71384602/2182349

On a CentOS 7 box, I added these lines to **/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service**

```
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown -R mongod.mongod /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb
PermissionsStartOnly=true
PIDFile=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
Type=forking
```

> mongod --version db version v5.0.15

Answer (score 0):

In my case /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock was owned by root:root. I've deleted the file and restarted like the accepted answer did and after that the file was owned by mongodb:mongodb.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).