# Unable to run mongoDB after installation

Tags: linux, mongodb, systemd

I'm On fedora 34 and trying to install mongoDB on this machine.
I followed installation instruction from official Docs [from here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/). Everything installed correctly, but now i'm unable to start the service.
I executed `sudo systemctl start mongod` and it showed

```
root@fedora /v/l/mongodb [100]# systemctl start mongod
Job for mongod.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mongod.service" and "journalctl -xeu mongod.service" for details.
```

This is the source for mongod.service in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=MongoDB Database Server
Documentation=https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
User=mongod
Group=mongod
Environment="OPTIONS=-f /etc/mongod.conf"
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/mongod
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb
PermissionsStartOnly=true
PIDFile=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
Type=forking
# file size
LimitFSIZE=infinity
# cpu time
LimitCPU=infinity
# virtual memory size
LimitAS=infinity
# open files
LimitNOFILE=64000
# processes/threads
LimitNPROC=64000
# locked memory
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
# total threads (user+kernel)
TasksMax=infinity
TasksAccounting=false
# Recommended limits for mongod as specified in
# https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/ulimit/#recommended-ulimit-settings

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I think problem begins here

```
 12 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS
```

I'm a noob in systemd and daemons and services

This is the log from `systemctl status mongod.service`

```
root@fedora /v/l/mongodb [1]# systemctl status mongod.service
× mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2021-08-01 11:18:36 IST; 16min ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 8116 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 8117 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 8118 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 8119 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=14)
        CPU: 149ms

Aug 01 11:18:36 fedora systemd[1]: Starting MongoDB Database Server...
Aug 01 11:18:36 fedora mongod[8119]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
Aug 01 11:18:36 fedora mongod[8122]: forked process: 8122
Aug 01 11:18:36 fedora mongod[8119]: ERROR: child process failed, exited with 14
Aug 01 11:18:36 fedora mongod[8119]: To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.
Aug 01 11:18:36 fedora systemd[1]: mongod.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=14/n/a
Aug 01 11:18:36 fedora systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 01 11:18:36 fedora systemd[1]: Failed to start MongoDB Database Server.
```

Comment: likely file permission issue, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64608581/mongodb-code-exited-status-14-failed-but-not-any-clear-errors

Answer (score 0):

Your mongodb exited with status code 14 as systemctl status says.

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/823288/mongodb-loads-but-breaks-returning-status-14#:%7E:text=According%20to%20the%20mongo%2Ddocs,performing%20a%20clean%20shut%20down.%22) you can find the answer