# Cant run mongodb inside a docker container with centos

Tags: mongodb, docker, centos

I am using ansible to install mongodb in an automated way.
This works without problems from on a normal server.
However, I now want to install mongodb in a Docker container running centos.

The installation itself works but I can't start the mongodb inside the docker container.

output if the command "service mongod status" is following:

```
    mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Mon 2022-03-07 09:05:57 UTC; 18min ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 3410 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3409 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3408 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3407 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 07 09:04:27 35664f872c49 systemd[1]: Starting MongoDB Database Server...
Mar 07 09:04:27 35664f872c49 mongod[3410]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
Mar 07 09:04:27 35664f872c49 mongod[3410]: forked process: 3412
Mar 07 09:04:29 35664f872c49 systemd[1]: New main PID 3412 does not belong to service, and PID file is not owned by root. Refusing.
Mar 07 09:04:29 35664f872c49 systemd[1]: New main PID 3412 does not belong to service, and PID file is not owned by root. Refusing.
Mar 07 09:05:57 35664f872c49 systemd[1]: mongod.service start operation timed out. Terminating.
Mar 07 09:05:57 35664f872c49 systemd[1]: Failed to start MongoDB Database Server.
Mar 07 09:05:57 35664f872c49 systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
Mar 07 09:05:57 35664f872c49 systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
```

my mongod.conf looks like

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  wiredTiger:

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1  # Enter 0.0.0.0,:: to bind to all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses or, alternatively, use the net.bindIpAll setting.


#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

output of "journalctl -xe"

```
Mar 07 09:04:23 35664f872c49 sudo[3339]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 07 09:04:23 35664f872c49 ansible-file[3342]: Invoked with directory_mode=None force=False remote_src=None _original_basename=tmpvzT2ge path=/etc/systemd/system/pyuge-credentials.ini ow
Mar 07 09:04:23 35664f872c49 sudo[3339]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Mar 07 09:04:23 35664f872c49 systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of root.
-- Subject: Unit user-0.slice has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit user-0.slice has finished shutting down.
Mar 07 09:04:24 35664f872c49 sudo[3386]: xxx : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/sh -c echo BECOME-SUCCESS-mcndulcbbhooqfkygoaipglzcaonaqfb ; /usr/bin/python /home/
Mar 07 09:04:24 35664f872c49 systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of root.
-- Subject: Unit user-0.slice has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit user-0.slice has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
Mar 07 09:04:24 35664f872c49 systemd[1]: Started Session c167 of user root.
-- Subject: Unit session-c167.scope has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit session-c167.scope has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
Mar 07 09:04:24 35664f872c49 sudo[3386]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 07 09:04:24 35664f872c49 ansible-systemd[3389]: Invoked with no_block=False force=None name=mongod daemon_reexec=False enabled=True daemon_reload=True state=started user=None scope=Non
Mar 07 09:04:25 35664f872c49 systemd[1]: Reloading.
Mar 07 09:04:27 35664f872c49 systemd[1]: Starting MongoDB Database Server...
-- Subject: Unit mongod.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit mongod.service has begun starting up.
Mar 07 09:04:27 35664f872c49 mongod[3410]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
Mar 07 09:04:27 35664f872c49 mongod[3410]: forked process: 3412
Mar 07 09:04:29 35664f872c49 mongod[3410]: child process started successfully, parent exiting
Mar 07 09:04:29 35664f872c49 systemd[1]: New main PID 3412 does not belong to service, and PID file is not owned by root. Refusing.
Mar 07 09:04:29 35664f872c49 systemd[1]: New main PID 3412 does not belong to service, and PID file is not owned by root. Refusing.
Mar 07 09:05:57 35664f872c49 systemd[1]: mongod.service start operation timed out. Terminating.
Mar 07 09:05:57 35664f872c49 systemd[1]: Failed to start MongoDB Database Server.
-- Subject: Unit mongod.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit mongod.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Mar 07 09:05:57 35664f872c49 systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
Mar 07 09:05:57 35664f872c49 systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
Mar 07 09:05:57 35664f872c49 sudo[3386]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Mar 07 09:05:57 35664f872c49 systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of root.
-- Subject: Unit user-0.slice has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit user-0.slice has finished shutting down.
```

EDIT: Output of mongd.log

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:27.877+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"-","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:27.877+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:27.878+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"main","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:27.882+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:27.883+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:28.122+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:28.123+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:28.123+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:28.123+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:28.123+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":3412,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongo","architecture":"64-bit","host":"35664f872c49"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:28.123+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.6","gitVersion":"212a8dbb47f07427dae194a9c75baec1d81d9259","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"rhel70","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:28.123+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)","version":"Kernel 3.10.0-1160.45.1.el7.x86_64"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:28.123+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/etc/mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1","port":27017},"processManagement":{"fork":true,"pidFilePath":"/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid","timeZoneInfo":"/usr/share/zoneinfo"},"storage":{"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongo","journal":{"enabled":true}},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:28.125+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"/var/lib/mongo","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:28.125+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=406M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),builtin_extension_config=(zstd=(compression_level=6)),file_manager=(close_idle_time=600,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:28.597+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1646643868:597683][3412:0x7fe97f43dbc0], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 6 through 7"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:28.693+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1646643868:693732][3412:0x7fe97f43dbc0], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 7 through 7"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:28.785+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1646643868:785593][3412:0x7fe97f43dbc0], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_ALL] Main recovery loop: starting at 6/6016 to 7/256"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:28.883+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1646643868:883641][3412:0x7fe97f43dbc0], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 6 through 7"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:28.944+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1646643868:944158][3412:0x7fe97f43dbc0], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 7 through 7"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:28.991+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1646643868:991219][3412:0x7fe97f43dbc0], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_ALL] Set global recovery timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:28.991+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1646643868:991279][3412:0x7fe97f43dbc0], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_ALL] Set global oldest timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:28.992+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1646643868:992252][3412:0x7fe97f43dbc0], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 1, snapshot max: 1 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 65"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:28.999+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger opened","attr":{"durationMillis":874}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:28.999+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:29.000+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4366408, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"No table logging settings modifications are required for existing WiredTiger tables","attr":{"loggingEnabled":true}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:29.008+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22262,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor starting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:29.010+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22120,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:29.011+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22178,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'. We suggest setting it to 'never'","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:29.011+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22181,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'. We suggest setting it to 'never'","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:29.015+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915702, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Updated wire specification","attr":{"oldSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true},"newSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":13,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":13,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:29.015+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":5071100, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Clearing temp directory"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:29.015+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20536,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Flow Control is enabled on this deployment"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:29.016+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20625,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture","attr":{"dataDirectory":"/var/lib/mongo/diagnostic.data"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:29.023+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":6015317, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Setting new configuration state","attr":{"newState":"ConfigReplicationDisabled","oldState":"ConfigPreStart"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:29.025+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:29.025+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"127.0.0.1"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:29.025+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:29.014+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"Checkpointer","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1646643929:14790][3412:0x7fe971a29700], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 3, snapshot max: 3 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 65"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.715+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23377,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Received signal","attr":{"signal":15,"error":"Terminated"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.715+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23378,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Signal was sent by kill(2)","attr":{"pid":1,"uid":0}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.715+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23381,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"will terminate after current cmd ends"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.716+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.716+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4794602, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Attempting to enter quiesce mode"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.716+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.716+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.717+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784903, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the LogicalSessionCache"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.718+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutdown: going to close listening sockets"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.729+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23017,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"removing socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.729+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.729+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784906, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the FlowControlTicketholder"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.729+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20520,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.729+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784908, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the PeriodicThreadToAbortExpiredTransactions"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.730+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784909, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicationCoordinator"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.730+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784910, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the ShardingInitializationMongoD"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.730+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784911, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Enqueuing the ReplicationStateTransitionLock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.730+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784912, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Killing all operations for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.730+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4695300, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Interrupted all currently running operations","attr":{"opsKilled":3}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.730+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"TENANT_M", "id":5093807, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down all TenantMigrationAccessBlockers on global shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.730+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784913, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down all open transactions"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.730+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784914, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Acquiring the ReplicationStateTransitionLock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.730+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":4784915, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the IndexBuildsCoordinator"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.730+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784916, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Reacquiring the ReplicationStateTransitionLock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.730+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784917, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Attempting to mark clean shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.730+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.730+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.730+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22582,   "ctx":"MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor","msg":"Killing all outstanding egress activity."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.730+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784923, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the ServiceEntryPoint"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.730+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.730+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20609,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.730+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.730+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784928, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the TTL monitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.730+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":3684100, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down TTL collection monitor thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.730+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":3684101, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Finished shutting down TTL collection monitor thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.730+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.730+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784930, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down the storage engine"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.730+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22320,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down journal flusher thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.730+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22321,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Finished shutting down journal flusher thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.730+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22322,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down checkpoint thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.730+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22323,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Finished shutting down checkpoint thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.730+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20282,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Deregistering all the collections"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.730+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22261,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Timestamp monitor shutting down"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.731+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22317,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.731+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22318,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down session sweeper thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.731+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22319,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Finished shutting down session sweeper thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.731+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795902, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Closing WiredTiger","attr":{"closeConfig":"leak_memory=true,"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.732+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1646643957:732369][3412:0x7fe97a23a700], close_ckpt: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 6, snapshot max: 6 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 65"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.741+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795901, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"WiredTiger closed","attr":{"durationMillis":10}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.741+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22279,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"shutdown: removing fs lock..."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.741+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.741+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down full-time data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.741+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20626,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down full-time diagnostic data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.744+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.745+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":0}}
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Check the mongod logfile `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`

Comment: I've edited my question and added the output of the log. I still dont know the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution for that problem. I've needed to change the mongod.service file in "/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service".

The file looks now like:

```
 [Unit]
Description=MongoDB Database Server
Documentation=https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=root
Environment="OPTIONS=-f /etc/mongod.conf"
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/mongod
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown -R root:root /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb
PermissionsStartOnly=true
PIDFile=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
Type=forking
# file size
LimitFSIZE=infinity
# cpu time
LimitCPU=infinity
# virtual memory size
LimitAS=infinity
# open files
LimitNOFILE=64000
# processes/threads
LimitNPROC=64000
# locked memory
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
# total threads (user+kernel)
TasksMax=infinity
TasksAccounting=false
# Recommended limits for mongod as specified in
# https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/ulimit/#recommended-ulimit-settings

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've changed User and Group to root. And edited the line:

```
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb
```

to:

```
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown -R root:root /var/run/mongodb
```

Everything works now as expected.

Outside of the container it works perfectly fine with the out-of-the-box configuration. Seems to be a root or permission problem with the container.

Comment: This saved me. All morning I've been trying to figure out what went wrong. My Mongo instance on AWS had been working for over a month, then one day it stopped. I could cry  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was corrupt directory in MongoDB database `diagnostic.data` which had gone corrupt due to improper shutdown or filesystem error because of dual boot

```
I just deleted this directory **diagnostic.data**
```

I would also suggest you to update permissions and see if any error rises during permissions updates

```
sudo chown -R mongod:mongod /var/run/mongod
//if you have changed user/group or database directory then change accordingly
```

It will show any file or directory which is problematic for MongoDB to read or write. Then you can delete and try again or re-create deleted directory with new permissions.

Answer (score 0):

According this line

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:04:29.025+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
```

the service started successfully. But one hour later

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.715+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23377,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Received signal","attr":{"signal":15,"error":"Terminated"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-03-07T09:05:57.715+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23378,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Signal was sent by kill(2)","attr":{"pid":1,"uid":0}}
```

there was an attempt to stop the service. Over all everything look normal.